# Shared Preferences MODE_APPEND constant is not recognised

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to append data on my already existing preferences, but it seems like the MODE_APPEND
constant is not recognised. Despite the error, the program can be executed, but the content of preferences is overwritten.

[image]

I've already searched for a solution but didn't find anything. What might be the problem?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Expected Scenario:

**After first program execution**

```
array.add("ONE");array.add("TWO");array.add("THREE");
set=new HashSet<String>(array);
editor.putStringSet(key, set);
print(prefs);
```

Output

> [ONE, TWO, THREE]

**After second program execution**

```
array.add("FOUR");array.add("FIVE");array.add("SIX");
set=new HashSet<String>(array);
editor.putStringSet(key, set);
print(prefs);
```

Output

> [ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX]

Comment: clean the project, and possibly clear caches

Comment: Already invalidated caches and restarted / cleaned project with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer in relation to

> The solution you provided does not append new values. It overwrites them

The following is a set of methods that can be used to append to an existing shared preferences set.

```
public void appendSharedPreference(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String key, Object o) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor e = sharedPreferences.edit();
    for (Map.Entry<String,?> entry: sharedPreferences.getAll().entrySet()) {
        sharedPrefPut(e,entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
    }
    sharedPrefPut(e,key,o);
    e.commit();
}

public void sharedPrefPut(SharedPreferences.Editor e, String key, Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Boolean) e.putBoolean(key,(Boolean) o);
    if (o instanceof String) e.putString(key,(String) o);
    if (o instanceof Integer) e.putInt(key,(Integer) o);
    if (o instanceof Long) e.putLong(key,(Long) o);
    if (o instanceof Float) e.putFloat(key,(Float) o);
    if (o instanceof Set) e.putStringSet(key,(Set<String>) o);
}
```

An example of using this, within an Activity, is :-

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor e1 = this.getSharedPreferences("test",0).edit();
    e1.putInt("KEY1",100);
    e1.putString("KEY2","MYDATA");
    e1.commit();

    for (Map.Entry<String,?> e: this.getSharedPreferences("test",0).getAll().entrySet()) {
        Log.d("SPINITIAL","Key is " + e.getKey() + " Value is " + e.getValue());
    }

    appendSharedPreference(this.getSharedPreferences("test",0),"KEYAPPENDANOTHER","SomeOtherData");

    for (Map.Entry<String,?> e: this.getSharedPreferences("test",0).getAll().entrySet()) {
        Log.d("SPEND","Key is " + e.getKey() + " Value is " + e.getValue());
    }
```

The log produced from the above

Before

> D/SPINITIAL: Key is KEY2 Value is MYDATA
>
> D/SPINITIAL: Key is KEY1 Value is 100

After

> D/SPEND: Key is KEY2 Value is MYDATA
>
> D/SPEND: Key is KEY1 Value is 100
>
> D/SPEND: Key is KEYAPPENDANOTHER Value is SomeOtherData

Of course, over use/abuse of SharedPreferences can have performance ramifications

**Edit about Edit**

A method (subtle change) can be used like

```
public void replaceSharedPreference(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key, Object o) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor e = sharedPreferences.edit();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry: sharedPreferences.getAll().entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().equals(key)) {
            sharedPrefPut(e,entry.getKey(),o);
        } else {
            sharedPrefPut(e,entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

So instead of appending a new it will replace the existing. The object passed has to be built and for your requirement it needs the existing object to be extracted and appended to.

An example based upon your requirements could be :-

```
    ArrayList<String> array =  new ArrayList<>();
    array.add("ONE");array.add("TWO");array.add("THREE");
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>(array);

    SharedPreferences.Editor e1 = this.getSharedPreferences("test",0).edit();
    e1.putInt("KEY1",100);
    e1.putString("KEY2","MYDATA");
    e1.putStringSet("KEY3",set);
    e1.commit();

    for (Map.Entry<String,?> e: this.getSharedPreferences("test",0).getAll().entrySet()) {
        Log.d("SPINITIAL","Key is " + e.getKey() + " Value is " + e.getValue());
    }

    //appendSharedPreference(this.getSharedPreferences("test",0),"KEYAPPENDANOTHER","SomeOtherData");
    ArrayList<String> appendset = new ArrayList<>();
    appendset.add("FOUR");
    appendset.add("FIVE");
    appendset.add("SIX");
    HashSet<String> oldset = null;
    if ((oldset  = (HashSet<String>) this.getSharedPreferences("test",0).getStringSet("KEY3",null)) != null) {
         oldset.addAll(appendset);
         replaceSharedPreference(this.getSharedPreferences("test",0),"KEY3",oldset);
     }

    for (Map.Entry<String,?> e: this.getSharedPreferences("test",0).getAll().entrySet()) {
        Log.d("SPEND","Key is " + e.getKey() + " Value is " + e.getValue());
    }
```

If order is an issue then please note

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.
>   [Class HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Comment: I think I didn't describe correctly what is my desired result. Please check the edit on my original post.